# How to get this value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="CurrencyQuotePane">
    <div class="CurrencyQuote">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="form-label">Pair: </div><div>1/2</div>
            <div class="form-label padding-top">Spread: </div><div>385</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="form-label">Rate: </div><div>1/2</div>
            <div class="form-label padding-top">High/Low: </div><div>2002.0/0.0055</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

How do I get the 385 in Javascript if it keeps changing?

This is my current javascript:

```
function getSpread(){
    var tag = iframe.contentDocument.getElementByClassName('SPREAD');
    var spread = Number(tag[1].innerHTML);
    return spread;
}
```

Sorry if I don't know anything about javascript, I am a complete newbie.

Comment: Do you have an id or class for the div which contains 385??

Answer (score 5):

Change it to this:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="form-label">Pair: </div><div>TEXT</div>
    <div class="form-label padding-top">SPREAD</div><div id="spreadval">385</div>
</div>


function getSpread(){
    var tag = iframe.contentDocument.getElementById('spreadval');
    return parseInt(tag.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set id to your div

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="form-label">Pair: </div><div>TEXT</div>
  <div class="form-label padding-top">SPREAD</div><div id="changing_number">385</div>
</div>
```

get with jquery

```
$(function(){
   var theNumber = parseInt($('#changing_number').text());
});
```

or with DOM:

```
$(function(){
   var theNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('changing_number').innerHTML);

});
```

here you can learn js: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
var column = document.getElementsByClassName('column');
var divs = column[0].getElementsByTagName('div');
alert(divs[1].innerHTML);
```